# GLES20Canvas.nDrawDisplayList is slow

Tags: android, graphics, render

I have a custom view that I am trying to display, however I am seeing a bunch of jitter on it.
Everything scrolls slow and it isn't as responsive as it should be.

I used traceview and saw that

GLES20Canvas.nDrawDisplayList

seems responsible for taking a lot of time to execute.

Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GLES20Canvas.nDrawDisplayList is expected to have a large portion of the time if you are drawing a lot, especially very big views.
If you are seeing this all over your traceview the answer is "DRAW LESS"

In my specific issue I was drawing a large alpha layer over large views.
I would recommend reading the Do's and Dont's from [Android 3.0 Hardware Acceleration by Romain Guy](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-30-hardware-acceleration.html)

Comment: I've run this analysis on different devices for the same activities, fragments, and views. I only see the large delay on nDrawDisplayList on the HTC one device (http://stackoverflow.com/a/21791909/546901). People in other threads report this traceview result being device specific (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22514). Other devices have healthy traceview results. It seems like it is likely a device or OS-level issue. Most people seem to observe it on ScrollView or ListView.

Comment: I'm using Galaxy S4 for testing, Hardware acceleration is on by default (Target API Level 19), by putting `android:layerType="software"` on my `GridView` the rendering actually got faster. Note: don't use this as a final solution, try to find the root cause.